# Problem with installing Ubuntu on my macbook

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, live-usb

I am installing Ubuntu on my macbook with an USB stick. The USB stick booted and i started the installation. When it asks me to restart to complete the installation i do so. But when i start up again in only boots from the USB and i have to start all over again. If i take out the USB stick it does not boot at all. If i open the internal drive in a live session from my USB stick i can however see the folders and files that ubuntu has installed. If i hold alt while starting up i get another option for booting other than the USB stick which has the name "windows" even though i never have had installed windows or tried to do so. When i try to boot that option it goes into a command line which says "error: filesystem unknown" and "grub rescue".

After advice from an IRC i tried installing rEFInd. I tried all the installation methods however none of them work.

How do i fix this so i can boot up ubuntu from my internal drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of installing Ubuntu on a Mac.

1. Legacy Boot - Use the Mac variant of Ubuntu which you can download from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso).

Install rEFInd before you install Ubuntu. Now, create a partition for Ubuntu using either Disk Utility or GParted and install normally. When you reboot after the installation finishes, rEFInd will load and give you an option to select either OS X or Ubuntu.

This is the easier method and is convenient if you are dual booting.

2. EFI Boot - Use the normal variant of Ubuntu.

This method is slightly tough because you will have to delete the grub partition created by the Ubuntu installer (on a FAT partition) and install grub on an HFS partition, failing which your mac will not boot. However, this method works better if you want to completely replace OS X with Ubuntu.

Refer to [this website](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/) for steps to the EFI Boot method.